# generalization of tetrahedron

Tags: general-topology

I just want to know how to locate n+1 points in n dimensional real space such that the distance between any two points is 1 e.g. can you guys help me please?

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex should be able to help you out.

Comment: I think this is not what I want..

Comment: This describes the general format of the solid whose vertices are exactly the set you describe. The edges are of course wrong.  Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell looks better for your purposes?

Comment: It's easier to locate the n+1 points in a hyperplane in n+1 dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

You might check the proof of

[Cartesian coordinates for vertices of a regular 16-simplex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375525/cartesian-coordinates-for-vertices-of-a-regular-16-simplex/1376052#1376052)

for a formula for the regular simplex vertices

Answer (score 1):

In the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian%20coordinates%20for%20regular%20n-dimensional%20simplex%20in%20Rn) under "Cartesian coordinates for regular n-dimensional simplex in R$^n$" a process is described that results in just this.  It works in any dimension.