# Inradius of regular simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, simplex, polytopes

Let $r_n$ denote the inradius of a regular $n$-simplex $\triangle^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $a$ denote the uniform edge length.

It is well-known that

$r_1 = a \frac{1}{2} \\
 r_2 = a \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{3} \\
 r_3 = a \frac{1}{12} \sqrt{6}$

But how to generalize $r_n$ to arbitrary dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we see in [Height of $n$-simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697870/height-of-n-simplex), the altitude (height) of a regular $n$-simplex
of edge length $a$ is

$$h_n = a\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}.$$

The inradius $r_n$ is the distance from the centroid of the 
regular $n$-simplex to the center of a hyperface, so
$r_n = \frac 1{n+1} h_n.$
Therefore

$$r_n = \frac a{n+1} \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}
= \frac{a}{\sqrt{2n(n+1)}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You might check the proof of

[Cartesian coordinates for vertices of a regular 16-simplex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375525/cartesian-coordinates-for-vertices-of-a-regular-16-simplex/1376052#1376052)

which gives, via an inductive midpoint construction,
the inradii as $h_n$ for a unit length regular $n$-simplex.